# In ASP.NET, how can a child window keep track of parent?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an application that produces many pages of content. In order to expedite review of the process, I have a linkbutton that opens a child window starting at the page I'm on so reviewers can enter comments. I open the child window in javascript

```
objCmtWindow = window.open(MyURL, "comments", "width=800,height=600,menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,directories=no");
objCmtWindow.focus();
```

The child window has some javascript (an excerpt from a larger script) to listen to an API in the parent window so that it can know what to load

```
function updtSlide(){
  if(window.opener.MyAPI)
  {
     window.opener.MyAPI.addEventListener("MyEnterBtn", function(e)
      {
        updtContent();
       });
   }
}
```

It works on load to grab the data with the function updtContent as part of the page load. When I click for the next page (MyEnterBtn) in the parent window, the child window is not updating for the next page data it needs to display. Is there a piece I'm missing to poll the parent window? Since the parent can operate independantly of the child, I really can't put the command in the next page button. I know the API is working correctly and emitting next page events.

Thank You

Comment: Working with multiple windows for something like this is more pain than it's worth.  I'd strongly recommend using something like a modal dialog (Bootstrap has a very nice one, that springs to mind).

Comment: I can look at that, though, my boss has it fixed in his mind to do it this way because he's seen it somewhere else.

Comment: @RT1138 Tell your boss that the 90's are over. People prefer [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and [jQuery UI dialogs](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) rather than entirely new browser windows.

Comment: Half of a programmer's job is learning how to diplomatically correct management.  If you can explain how the multi-window idea will loose him money then he'll soon change his mind.

Answer (score -1):

In the js function, the first 'opener' is spelled wrong.

Comment: No, just my too rushed retyping. Thanks for noticing